What was Axis's logic behind sailing Jewish refugees from Romania to Palestine?
I came accross the history of MV Struma and MV Mefkure that were transporting Jewish people, refugees from Europe, from Romania to Palestine but were lost in the process. From reading the articles linked, Zionist organisations that aimed with independence of Palestine with a Jewish presence and/or state, organized those transfers. Those were clandestine organisations since they were also performing (as did Betar) attacks in Palestine.
The article about the Mefkure says that the transport was acknowledged by Axis authorities, since:

Sailing instructions from the German naval authorities were for Morina
with 308 passengers to sail first, followed by Bulbul with 390 people,
and lastly by Mefküre with 320 refugees (the exact number may be
slightly different) on board

Also, one of the transport happened in February 1942 and the other in August 1944, so the Shoah was already on its way by the time. I am thus wondering why such a transport could have happened (I would have understood if it was made undercover).
Also several questions popped up:

British authorities refused Struma's passengers the authorization to disembark in Palestine: Didn't German attacks on Jewish people made them change their mind?
Did Romania authorized on her own these transports, or did Germany agree?
Where did these Jewish refugees come from?
And the main question: Why did the Germans let these transports go while they were killing the majority of Jewish they were able to arrest?

I am aware that the Nazis thought about deporting Jews in Madagascar, but my understanding was that it was only an idea. Did they want to shake British rule in Palestine by forcing them to accept more Jewish that the quotas authorized for?

Too many questions but to focus on the main one, are you assuming the Germans knew that the Turkish-flagged MV Mefküre was carrying Jews? Is there evidence that they did?

@BrianZ Yes I am assuming in my question that they knew. As said in the quote in the question: German authorities gave sailing instructions so they knew this was happening

They knew the ship was moving. Did they know the identities of who was on board? I don't read the quote as necessarily implying that they did. If you have evidence of that key fact, am edit would be helpful. The footnote seems to point to Finkelstein.

@BrianZ Well, I am not specialist of Romania in the 40s
But in an harbour, when a ship moves, some declaration must be made to the authorities, including the reason for the trip. If that was an undercover trip, it is legitimate from me to expect to find it written in the article. So the quote strongly implies it was a regular shipping, and thus German authorities knew who were aboard.
If you have elements tha say the contrary, I am happy to read them

@totalMongot So you're presuming an answer to the question you asked:  "Did Romania authorized on her own these transports, or did Germany agree?"

@Spencer For the MV Mefkure that Brian commented about, yes because it is written in the wikipedia article. But for the others?

There are too many question posed here, but I'll point you to Iordachi and Traşcə (2015) and Nicosia (2019) who show that it is entirely plausible that the Germans knowingly allowed the Romanian Jews on these ships to leave for Palestine. As represented most clearly by the Haavara Agreement of 1933, earlier Nazi policy was entirely supportive of Jewish emigration from Europe, particularly to Palestine. There was indeed a critical change of policy in 1941 under the so-called Final Solution where Jews were generally no longer allowed to leave from areas under direct German control. The Nazi's shift towards opposition to Zionist emigration around this time was in part connected to their efforts to find support in the Arab world. But particularly when it came to relatively outlying areas of southeast Europe like Romania, the policy was not always consistent. The diplomatic communications show that Romania in particular preferred to let their Jews leave (in exchange for payment), and Germany was not wholly effective in pushing back against this. Germany explicitly granted permission for Jewish refugees to leave from Romania and other territories as late as 1943, mostly by way of Turkey and sometimes in exchange for releases of imprisoned German nationals by Britain.
That is the general context, but there are a lot of basic facts that remain unresolved about the Mefküre incident. I did not find a source clearly explaining in a conclusive way why those particular refugees (including around 300 Jewish orphans from Transnistria) were allowed passage by the Germans. However, it may be of interest that an unsigned German intelligence report states that they "allowed the ships to depart... in order not to draw the suspects' attention" (qtd. in Patek 2012, p. 163). The suspects were Polish partisans, who Romania warned Germany were aboard the Mefküre. The precise meaning of this is not entirely clear, but it is the only direct statement I've seen regarding the intention behind releasing the ships. Although the Wikipedia article quoted in the question says that the ship was torpedoed by a Soviet submarine, this hasn't been fully proven. At the time, it was widely believed that Nazis rather than Soviets sank the ship.

IIRC one of the aims of the earlier Nazi policy to allow/encourage Jews to emigrate was to confiscate/steal as much money as possible from them.  There was an exit tax and 1930s Nazi Germany was always short on foreign exchange.

People in positions of power in the Axis did occasionally act inconsistently with the policy of complete extermination of the Jews or take bribes to allow Jews to escape Sending some to Palestine was a reasonable choice because Jews would want to go there, it would enrage the Arabs and lead to revolt against the British near the Suez canal, and some Zionists were actively fighting the British. Also, to pack them on a ship at a nearby port would be easier than sending them to Russia, Spain, or England.
